# Stop tab completion suggesting 'messagebus'

Tags: zsh, osx, autocomplete

I've got a directory called `build`, which I `cd` into quite a bit.

If there isn't any directory `bu*` in the current directory, `zsh` tab completion: `cd bu`<kbd>TAB</kbd> suggests `messagebus/`, which isn't in `.`. If I accept that completion, I end up in `/private/var/empty`.

I'm unsure which `zsh` option suggests this completion, but I'd love to turn it off. Any idea which setting does it?

For what it's worth, this is on `OS X`. On `ubuntu`, I get the suggestions `libuuid messagebus` with identical `zsh` settings.

Comment: Does this happen if you run `zsh -f` (no config file)? If you run `ZDOTDIR=/ zsh` (only the system config file)? Since there are a lot of completion settings, it would help to know where this behavior is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

`/private/var/empty` is likely the `messagebus` user's home directory. `zsh` offers expansion of home directories when it receives an argument to the `cd` function that it thinks looks like a user name. In your case, `bu` is expanded to `messagebus` by the approximate matcher, because no more specific matcher will trigger in an empty directory (on your Linux system, both `uuid` and `messagebus` are returned as possible approximate matches for the string `bu`).

It's possible to tell `zsh` which users it should consider for expansion in these circumstances by putting something like this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' users user1 user2 root
```

Simply list all users you want the shell to consider, `source ~/.zshrc` to pick up the changes, and you should no longer get `messagebus` etc as possible completions.